# Meaning of certain statement is true for infinitely many

Tags: real-analysis, logic

In analysis I found the phrases that statement is true for all but a finite values of $n$  and statement is true for infinitely many values of $n$....I know that if statement is true for all but finite means that there are some finite values that does not satisfy the statement.....but please tell me in phrase infinitely many, if statement is true for infinitely many values then does it means that it is not true for infinitely many values?

Comment: suppose it is true if and only if $n$ is even

Comment: That a statement is true for all but finitely many values does NOT mean there are some finite values for which it is false. It means that the set of values for which the statement is false is a finite set. This finite set may be the empty set,

Comment: That a statement is true for infinitely many values means exactly that and no more.... $n\in \mathbb N\implies n\in \mathbb N$ is true for infinitely many $n$ and false for none.... $n\in \mathbb N\implies n/2\in \mathbb N$ is true for infinitely many $n$ and false for infinitely many $n$.... $n\in \mathbb N\implies n>1$ is true for infinitely many $n$ and false for just one $n$ (that is, for $n=1$).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is maybe, but not necessarily.

Two examples:

1) There are infinitely many values $p \in \mathbb{N}$ which are prime. (It is also not true for infinitely many values in $\mathbb{N}$).

2) There are infinitely many values $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n > 5$. (It is not true for only finitely many values in $\mathbb{N}$).